# SwiftUI Child Overflow

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In SwiftUI, is there a way to have a parent view maintain a fixed size even if the child view is larger? In this example below, the parent grows to fit the contents of the child even if you explicitly set a frame size on the parent:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      ChildView()
      VStack {
        Text("Parent")
        Spacer()
      }
    }
    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    .background(Color.red)
    .border(Color.black)
  }
}

struct ChildView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Child")
    }
    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    .background(Color.blue)
  }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

I want the "Parent" text to stay within the frame of the parent, but it gets pushed up because the child view is larger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because SwiftUI layout works differently - parent stack fits to content by default. We take `ZStack` and place in it `ChildView` and `ZStack` immediately becomes of its size, then we place `VStack` in `ZStack` and `Spacer` expands it to full size, ie. `ChildView`'s size as it is biggest, then we apply `.frame` that just generate view of requested size from original `ZStack` and because it is transparent, by default, we see all content of `ZStack`. Then we apply border to this resulting view (but still see `ZStack`'s content for same transparency reason)... and so on.

The effect which you want to achieve is

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      ChildView()
      VStack {
        Text("Parent")
        Spacer()
      }
      .frame(width: 100, height: 100)     // << here !!
      .border(Color.black)
    }
    .background(Color.red)
  }
}
```